# Jasmine tests fail on: Component is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I was getting this error for pretty much all of my tests, after creating a new component:

```
SampleComponent > should create
Failed: Component TuzGraphComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.
Error: Component TuzGraphComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.
    at JitCompiler._createCompiledHostTemplate (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25493:1)
    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25469:1
    at <Jasmine>
    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25466:1
    at <Jasmine>
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25455:1)
    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25393:1
    at Object.then (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:2166:27)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25391:1)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25353:1)
Error: Component TuzGraphComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.
Error: Component TuzGraphComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.
    at JitCompiler._createCompiledHostTemplate (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25493:1)
    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25469:1
    at <Jasmine>
    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25466:1
    at <Jasmine>
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25455:1)
    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25393:1
    at Object.then (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:2166:27)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25391:1)
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm2015/compiler.js:25350:1)
Expected undefined to be truthy.
Error: Expected undefined to be truthy.
    at <Jasmine>
    at UserContext.<anonymous> (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/src/app/sandboxviews/sample/sample.component.spec.ts:85:23)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:359:1)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js:308:1)
```

So I added the `TuzGraphComponent` into the declarations of all my tests.

First of all, there MUST be an easier way to do this than adding any new component manually to each existing test file?!?!

Anyway, this fixed most of the tests. There were still a few files with the same error, but one by one, as I opened the files and compared them, the failures disappeared. I can't really tell what changed; in one of those files I simply hit "Reformat File" in Webstorm and that appeared to fix it, in another file I moved a `{` that was on its own line back onto the line above it (result:`({`) and that appeared to fix it.

But there is still one test file that is failing, with the same error; it's actually the error I've posted above.

I'll paste in that file here, maybe someone else can spot the difference?

```js
import {async, ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';

import {AccessdeniedComponent} from '../../pages/accessdenied/accessdenied.component';
import {AppMainComponent} from '../../app.main.component';
import {AppSubMenuComponent, LeftmenuComponent} from '../../leftmenu/leftmenu.component';
import {CalibrationComponent} from '../calibration/calibration.component';
import {ControlComponent} from '../control/control.component';
import {DataviewerComponent} from '../dataviewer/dataviewer.component';
import {ExperimentComponent} from '../experiment/experiment.component';
import {FilemanagerComponent} from '../filemanager/filemanager.component';
import {FooterComponent} from '../../footer/footer.component';
import {HeaderbarComponent} from '../../headerbar/headerbar.component';
import {LoginComponent} from '../../pages/login/login.component';
import {MethodComponent} from '../method/method.component';
import {NotfoundComponent} from '../../pages/notfound/notfound.component';
import {TuneComponent} from '../tune/tune.component';
import {AccordionModule} from 'primeng/accordion';
import {AppRoutingModule} from '../../app-routing.module';
import {BlockUIModule} from 'primeng/blockui';
import {CheckboxModule} from 'primeng/checkbox';
import {DialogModule} from 'primeng/dialog';
import {DropdownModule} from 'primeng/dropdown';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {InputSwitchModule} from 'primeng/inputswitch';
import {InputTextModule} from 'primeng/inputtext';
import {OverlayPanelModule} from 'primeng/overlaypanel';
import {SampleComponent} from './sample.component';
import {ScrollPanelModule, SpinnerModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
import {TableModule} from 'primeng/table';
import {TuzGraphComponent} from '../tuz-graph/tuz-graph.component';

describe('SampleComponent', () => {
  let component: SampleComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<SampleComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AccessdeniedComponent,
        AppMainComponent,
        AppSubMenuComponent,
        CalibrationComponent,
        ControlComponent,
        DataviewerComponent,
        ExperimentComponent,
        FilemanagerComponent,
        FooterComponent,
        HeaderbarComponent,
        LeftmenuComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        MethodComponent,
        NotfoundComponent,
        SampleComponent,
        TuneComponent,
        TuzGraphComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        AccordionModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        BlockUIModule,
        CheckboxModule,
        DialogModule,
        DropdownModule,
        FormsModule,
        InputSwitchModule,
        InputTextModule,
        OverlayPanelModule,
        ScrollPanelModule,
        SpinnerModule,
        TableModule
      ]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SampleComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I haved a similar issue. i dont know what is the origin of the problem but run all previous test of your sample.component.spec.ts one by one and open the web console !. Be sure in each test that u dont have any error in your console and then run all test together again !. sometimes you have a error that dont get a failure in test but damage the next ones

Answer (score 0):

The reason you have to provide your new component in all of your tests is that you declare the real components as dependencies instead of mocking them in each spec file.
Right now at least one of your dependencies depends on your new component, so you must then also declare your new component.

Instead you should have fake components that stand in for your real ones. In your example you are testing the SampleComponent. It should be the only real declaration you have. Everything else should be faked.

Here is an example of how to fake AccessDeniedComponent

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-access-denied',
  template: `<div>Access Denied</div>`,
})
export class FakeAccessDeniedComponent{
  // any public input/outputs the real one has
  // any public method necessary for your tests
}
```

In this case you will want the fake to have the same selector as the real one and the same public inputs/outputs/methods used outside of the file. In your SampleComponent spec you would now declare FakeAccessDeniedComponent instead of the real one.

In your tests themselves they should only expect that you have passed in data to the inputs, called the methods, or listened to the outputs. Any such output event should be faked in test that needs it.

For AOT to work you'll want to add your fake components to a fake module. That fake module doesn't need to be imported by anything.

Pretending that you go through all of your dependencies you'll likely not need to import as many modules, as you only need to import the modules that SampleComponent needs to work. You'll also likely not need to declare as many components, as you'll only need what SampleComponent depends on.

Comment: Thanks Wesley. I think I understand what you're saying; that basically if I'm testing one component I should isolate it from others, and not need to import/declare anything. So I went to one of the files, `tune.component.ts`, and I see that it doesn't import or refer to any other components. I tried commenting lines out of the declarations of `tune.component.spec.ts`, thinking that it should be fine if that component isn't used in the component under test, but commenting any, or even all (except `TuneComponent` itself of course), still gave errors about those components. Thoughts?

Comment: Usually it all depends on the html elements in your component's html. If you have a reference to 2 or 3 other components then you would declare fake components with the same selectors so that your component under test knows what to draw.
With that said, I'm guessing you did an fdescribe to only run the tests for the one component you're looking at? I would take it one component at a time for sure.
I would even go as far as to remove all declarations, modules, and providers and then add them back to fix the errors you see. If it still wants your new component I would dig to see why.

Answer (score 0):

```
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AccessdeniedComponent,
        AppMainComponent,
        AppSubMenuComponent,
        CalibrationComponent,
        ControlComponent,
        DataviewerComponent,
        ExperimentComponent,
        FilemanagerComponent,
        FooterComponent,
        HeaderbarComponent,
        LeftmenuComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        MethodComponent,
        NotfoundComponent,
        SampleComponent,
        TuneComponent,
        TuzGraphComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        AccordionModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        BlockUIModule,
        CheckboxModule,
        DialogModule,
        DropdownModule,
        FormsModule,
        InputSwitchModule,
        InputTextModule,
        OverlayPanelModule,
        ScrollPanelModule,
        SpinnerModule,
        TableModule
      ]
    }).overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, { set: { entryComponents: [TuzGraphComponent] } })
      .compileComponents();
  }));
```